# A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame - tried previous solutions

Tags: python, pandas

This has come up a lot, but proposed answers don't seem to help.

I have a datetime column which I'm trying to convert to d/m/y h:m format.

I'm using the following code:

```
change_details.loc[:, 'Planned Start Date'] = change_details['Planned Start Date'].dt.strftime('%d %m, %Y %h:%m')
```

Going by previous answers, this should be the right way to prevent this warning, but I'm still getting it:

> ```
> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
> Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
> ```

I've also tried suffixing with .copy() to no avail!

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you try and swap the way you are indexing? `loc` on the right and square brackets on the right. Just a hunch

Comment: Nope, same error! Using change_details['Planned Start Date'] = change_details.loc[:, 'Planned Start Date'].dt.strftime('%d %m, %Y %h:%m')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found my issue,

it was earlier in the code, where I originally sliced change_details from another dataframe.

```
change_details = gdp_sched_today[[start_date', 'end_date']]
change_details.columns = ['Planned Start Date', 'Planned End Date']
change_details['Planned Start Date'] = change_details['Planned Start Date'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %h:%M')
change_details['Planned End Date'] = change_details['Planned End Date'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
```

I was able to solve this by adding .copy() to that first line, making sure Pandas know I intended to make it a copy rather than a view.

```
change_details = gdp_sched_today[[start_date', 'end_date']].copy()
change_details.columns = ['Planned Start Date', 'Planned End Date']
change_details['Planned Start Date'] = change_details['Planned Start Date'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %h:%M')
change_details['Planned End Date'] = change_details['Planned End Date'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
```

sure would be nice if the warning was a bit clearer on what's triggering it :)